# Product share on Facebook does not show image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, social

I am trying to share my product on Facebook but my product image is missing on Facebook share page. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you using an extension for product share? Can you add the code which you are using to add share button?

Comment: hii sir thanks for reple i m not using any extension..just using .that code..... <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                      
      <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style" style="padding-top: 4px;"></a>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-538d2d303ab3eaa0"></script>
                    <!-- AddThis Button END -->